# Why are dispatch groups not waiting?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

I'm reading about GCD lately and trying to implement a series of network calls using the `DispatchGroup`, however, I'm am not seeing the desired results. If my understanding is correct whenever we use `wait` on the dispatch group it should block the thread until all enter and leaves are equal.In my case it not blocking the thread. Here is my piece of code

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    print("herer \(Thread.current)")
    var userAvatorsToLoad: [String] = []
    let url =  URL(string:"https://api.github.com/users")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse , response.statusCode == 200 {
            print("her\(Thread.current)")
            let userResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Users].self, from: data!)
            userAvatorsToLoad.append(contentsOf:[userResponse![0].avatar_url,
                                                 userResponse![1].avatar_url,
                                                 userResponse![2].avatar_url])
            userAvatorsToLoad.forEach {[weak self] (imageUrl) in
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                self?.loadImage(url: imageUrl) {
                    print("image Successfully cached")
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
        }
    }.resume()

    dispatchGroup.wait()
    print("hello")
}
```

In the output, I'm seeing `hello` even before any of my async operations are performed. Am i missing anything

Comment: I just figured out that all dispatch group operations must happen on the same thread for it to work. How do I achieve it in my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by the time you hit the `wait` call, it hadn’t yet encountered the `forEach` loop which was performing the `enter` and `leave` calls.

If you’re going to `wait` for an asynchronous request which is using the `enter`/`leave` calls, you’ll need to add a `enter`/`leave` for the main asynchronous request as well.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    var userAvatorsToLoad: [String] = []
    let url = URL(string:"https://api.github.com/users")!
    group.enter()               // ADD THIS ...
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        defer { group.leave() } // ... AND THIS
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse , response.statusCode == 200 {
            print("her\(Thread.current)")
            let userResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Users].self, from: data!)
            userAvatorsToLoad.append(contentsOf:[userResponse![0].avatar_url,
                                                 userResponse![1].avatar_url,
                                                 userResponse![2].avatar_url])
            userAvatorsToLoad.forEach {[weak self] (imageUrl) in
                group.enter()
                self?.loadImage(url: imageUrl) {
                    print("image Successfully cached")
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
        }
    }.resume()

    group.wait()
    print("hello")
}
```

---

But, you should generally avoid `wait`. Use `notify`.

```
let url =  URL(string:"https://api.github.com/users")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard
        let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 
        200 ..< 300 ~= response.statusCode,
        let data = data,
        let userResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Users].self, from: data)
    else {
        return
    }

    let userAvatorsToLoad = [
        userResponse[0].avatar_url,
        userResponse[1].avatar_url,
        userResponse[2].avatar_url
    ]

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    userAvatorsToLoad.forEach { imageUrl in
        group.enter()
        self.loadImage(url: imageUrl) {
            print("image Successfully cached")
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("Hello")
    }
}.resume()
```

This avoids blocking one of the very limited GCD worker threads while you perform the request. It also completely eliminates the need for the global concurrent queue at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move "dispatchGroup.enter()" before the "URLSession.shared.dataTask" methods will be called.
So the code will be:

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        print("herer \(Thread.current)")
        var userAvatorsToLoad: [String] = []
        let url =  URL(string:"https://api.github.com/users")!
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse , response.statusCode == 200 {
                print("her\(Thread.current)")
                let userResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Users].self, from: data!)
                userAvatorsToLoad.append(contentsOf:[userResponse![0].avatar_url,
                                                     userResponse![1].avatar_url,
                                                     userResponse![2].avatar_url])
                userAvatorsToLoad.forEach {[weak self] (imageUrl) in
                    dispatchGroup.enter()
                    self?.loadImage(url: imageUrl) {
                        print("image Successfully cached")
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                }
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }.resume()

        dispatchGroup.wait()
        print("hello")
    }
```

Comment: But then there will one enter and 3 leaves

Comment: The leave function have to been called after the foreach, I forgot to move out the function

Comment: Nope, It is still printing `hello`  before the load image operation is complete. The reason for that is enter and leave must happen on the same thread I believe.That is not happening here

Comment: Nope, the purpose of dispatchGroup is to control thread by other thread, I always use dispatchGroup with closure and promise and it work properly. Try to create a variable in the VC and not in the function where you assign the new dispatchGroup

Comment: Ahh. Then I wonder why this isn't working as expected. Moving it out to VC level hasn't changed anything

Comment: Sorry, but let me summarise, in the closure you create a dispatchGroup, then before to call URLSession.shared.dataTask(...) you call the enter() methods, after URLSession.shared.dataTask(...) you call the wait() function and inside the completion closure, at the of all, out of every if or something else you call leave() function. I'm right?

Comment: Yes. correct. Here is a link to the playground , if you want to play around https://github.com/Narik44/Leetcode/blob/master/DispatchGroups.playground/Contents.swift

Comment: Sorry, but now I found the solution that works, it's a merge of what you did and what I did, so you have to call enter before call task to increase the DispatchQueue count and to make sure that the thread will be stopped when wait() will be called, and than call enter for each image you have to load.